# Unexpected Gap between two out of three elements [CSS]

Tags: html, css, css-position, web-deployment

I have been brushing up on some CSS positioning since I lack proficiency in the said concept and I can across some unexpected and unexplained gaps between two out of the three containers. I will attached the code for HTML and CSS below along with the output screenshot to make it less arcane.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.red-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blue-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yellow-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-container"></div>
<div class="blue-container"></div>
<div class="yellow-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`flex-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), [flex in css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.red-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red-container"></div>
  <div class="blue-container"></div>
  <div class="yellow-container"></div>
</div>
```

to remove the gap without using `flex-box`

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="red container"></div>
<div class="blue container"></div>
<div class="yellow container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried flexbox before and that gap disappears but what I really meant was why does that gap persist if we have relative or absolute layouts. Guess I'll edit my question

Comment: you can see the edit